# How to remove key-value from JSON if it has empty value?

Tags: apex, rest-api, json

I have this inner Class which has contactInfo to be sent as JSON now I want to remove the one key value if that has empty value:

```
public class ContactInfo {
        public String town;
        public String State;
        public String Country;
    public ContactInfo(String town, String State, String Country){
    town = town;
    State = state;
    Country = Country;
    }
    }
```

---

```
{"ContactInfo":[
        {
        "town":"Bangalore",
        "State":"KA",
        "Country":"" // If this is case then remove this attribute itself
        }
       ]

}
```

I am using remove string for empty value which doesn't look good.

Comment: How do you want to remove it, through apex or JS?

Answer (score 9):

If you use **null** values, they will not be serialized when providing the "supressNulls" flag:

```
ContactInfo demo = new ContactInfo();
demo.town = 'Anywhere';
demo.State = 'New York';
demo.Country = null;
System.debug(json.serialize(demo, true));
```

Output:

```
{"demo":"Anywhere","State":"New York"}
```

Empty string values are still values. In almost all cases, Apex doesn't use empty strings, instead returning null. For most remaining cases, you can always use null explicitly:

```
demo.town = townInput == ''? null: townInput;
```

Comment: Wow, I didnt knew this param exists, I was using String replace to remove nulls. 
https://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/stripping-nulls-from-a-json-object-in-apex/

Comment: @PranayJaiswal This was a new feature sometime around Winter 15/Spring 15 (it's mentioned in the docs). Older API versions didn't suppress nulls, then there was one version that did, and then they let us specify.

Comment: We are using another class JSON generator to build the template and from this class sending the wrapperdata. Is there anyway I can do something like this ContactInfo.Country = null ? I have updated the class in question.

Comment: @shuklayogesh As long as you're using null values, you can suppress them. If you're getting empty strings, then someone did that intentionally and should be fixed. Since you have a constructor... `public ContactInfo(String town, String State, String Country) { this.town = town == ''? null: town; this.State = state == ''?: state; this.Country = Country == ''? null: country; }`

Comment: Isn't the default behavior `true` and you would only need to set it if you want to exhibit different behavior?

Comment: @AdrianLarson : It depends on the project/integrations/solutions/reciever handling/etc... Enjoy reading the debate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686995/should-null-values-be-included-in-json-responses-from-a-rest-api

Comment: @Answers_Seeker I wasn't asking about JSON generally or what the default behavior should be. I was asking what the default behavior *is* in **`Apex`**.

Comment: @AdrianLarson It depends on the API version. I forget the specifics, but if you're using a modern API version, the default is false, probably to match the historic behavior.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to remove with apex while serializing then use below method from JSON class

```
public static String serialize(Object objectToSerialize, Boolean suppressApexObjectNulls)
```

> suppressApexObjectNulls =>  Type: Boolean If true, remove null values
>   before serializing the JSON object.

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_methods)

If you are trying to delete from js then try

```
delete obj.ContactInfo.Country;
```